# Шифр Цезаря в питон. Латиница работает (ave, Caesar!), кириллица - нет

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, шифрование

Делаю задачу на старый добрый шифр Цезаря. Задаем смещение, шифруем-дешифруем текст:

```
a = int(input())   # смещение
b = input()        # текст
c = '!?., '        # нешифруемые символы 
def coder():
    for i in b:
        if i in c:
            print(chr(ord(i)), end='')
        if i.islower():
            if ord(i) + a > 122:   # кодировка последней строчной буквы в латинице
                print(chr(ord(i) + a - 26), end='')
            else:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a), end='')

        elif i.isupper():
            if ord(i) + a > 90:    # кодировка последней заглавной буквы в латинице
                print(chr(ord(i) + a - 26), end='')
            else:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a), end='')
    print()

coder()
```

С латиницей всё работает. Но когда переделал эту же программу под кириллицу (с учетом количества букв в алфавите и числового значения последних букв), прога стала выдавать непонятно что:

```
a = 1  # int(input())   # To be, or not to be, that is the question!
b = input()
c = '!?., '


def coder():
    for i in b:
        if i in c:
            print(chr(ord(i)), end='')
        if i.islower():
            if ord(i) + a > 255:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a - 32), end='')
            else:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a), end='')

        elif i.isupper():
            if ord(i) + a > 223:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a - 32), end='')
            else:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a), end='')
    print()


coder()
```

Когда вводишь "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя" со смещением +1, получается "БВГДЕЖвЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯа". Когда с тем же смещением ввести "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ", то получится "ϱϲϳϴϵ϶ϢϷϸϹϺϻϼϽϾϿЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЍЎЏА".
Возможно, проблема кроется в ASCII-table?
Для латиницы всё понятно: прописные идут с 65 по 90, строчные буквы с 97 по 122. См. [ASCII-table](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg).

Для кириллицы делал [по этой таблице](https://assistantstudent.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/d0b1d0b5d0b7d18bd0bcd18fd0bdd0bdd18b4.png?w=640) и тут всё по идее должно работать аналогично латинице (с поправкой на длину алфавита и  значение кода для цифры).
Нашел еще какую-то таблицу, где алфавит идет уже не сплошной, а с перерывами: [Extended character set (128 - 255)](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp866.html).
Есть пара предположений/идей, интересует ваше мнение на этот счет:

- я использую какую-то неправильную таблицу для кириллицы (тогда какая правильная?).
- нужно принудительно прописать кодировку (хотя я не знаю как это делается и какую вообще прописать).
  Или может просто сделать через проверку наличия символа в строках (lowercase_letters_cyrillic = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя' // uppercase_letters_cyrillic = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ') - а может вообще в одной длинной строке - и во вводимом тексте заменять букву прибавляя длину смещения к индексу цифры в строке?

Comment: Хорошая таблица для изучения кодировок прошлого века. В веке нынешнем тексты кодируются UNICODE. Там русский алфавит записан не совсем подряд. Я бы делал без `chr`/`odr`.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня была тоже идея сделать без chr / ord, тем более не очень они мне нравятся. Но как-то запутался в индексах))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ord(i) + a > 255:
```

Эта строка обрезает текст, если его код больше 255, а вот коды кириллических символов [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видишь они за 1000, так что это не работает, нужно использовать ord('я') как верхний лимит.

```
def coder():
    for i in b:
        if i in c:
            print(chr(ord(i)), end='')
        if i.islower():
            if ord(i) + a > ord('я'):
                print(chr(ord(i) + a - 32), end='')
            else:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a), end='')

        elif i.isupper():
            if ord(i) + a > ord('я'):
                print(chr(ord(i) + a - 32), end='')
            else:
                print(chr(ord(i) + a), end='')
    print()
```

(Так же Ё и ё находятся в конце, так что если нужно обрабатывать и их, придётся прописать для них исключения)

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало. Посмотрел какие там значения - for i in cyr_low:
    print(ord(i), end=' '), в общем совсем другие цифры были))